# URL rewriting - outgoing rules

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm new to the url rewrite module in IIS7, but I managed to add incoming rules and they work well.

Now I want to add outgoing rules to modify the urls in the served pages to reflect the new url scheme. Is there any way to set outbound rules like I set the inbound rules, with a rewrite map?

I looked, but couldn`t find an option to do that.

Comment: Do you mean write a rule, then all HTML rendered links are changed to match it?  If so, +1 would like to learn how to do this.

Comment: Yep. I got this working with an automatic rule, but thats not good enough for the type of rewrite I need.